# Not able to create text analytics resource in Azure Congnitive services

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I am not able to create text Analytics resource in West US 2 region , due to following error
I have selected all default values ( for ex : I have selected storage type as V1 )
In Text Analytics , I want to analyze PDF , WORD , EXCEL docs to extract phrases , hence selected storage ( and not Cognitive Search )

**{
"code": "InvalidTemplateDeployment",
"details": [
{
"code": "BringOwnFeatureNotEnabled",
"message": "Bring your own feature is not enabled for Subscription/SKU/Kind."
}
],
"message": "The template deployment 'TextAnalyticsCreate_Dx-20220130011000' is not valid according to the validation procedure. The tracking id is 'd62cf124-f927-4b00-b6b6-0f16ae94eadf'. See inner errors for details."
}**

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to use **customer managed key** in your Azure Cognitive Service deployment. This can't be done directly.

You need to first raise a request by using below link:

[Cognitive Services & Applied AI Customer Managed Keys and Bring Your Own Storage access request](https://forms.office.com/Pages/ResponsePage.aspx?id=v4j5cvGGr0GRqy180BHbR3k4-f_9d9xPhWkgOUub9YhUNDZJUERRVVVDME4xNDVNRjEwMTNZV1dHSS4u)

It takes 4-5 business days to get approved. Once approved, the feature responsible for the customer managed key will be enabled on the subscription. You won't get the above error after approval.